# C# GRAPHICS force to overwrite pixel

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, 2d

I'm currently coding a simple image manipulator with C# Bitmaps und Graphics. I'm using a costum transparent elemt and it works fine. in my Draw-Method I update the control by drawing to set image:

```
ImageAttributes attr = new ImageAttributes();  
attr.SetColorKey(this.transpKey, this.transpKey);  
Rectangle dstRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.image.Width, this.image.Height);  
e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.image, dstRect, 0, 0, this.image.Width, this.image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attr);  
e.Graphics.Dispose();
```

Now I need a function to erase some pixels. Using a Form and drawing on BackgroindImage I can "erase" pixels by using the TransparencyKey-Prperty. But this proterty doesn't exists in my costum control. That's the reason why I used "attr.SetColorKey(this.transpKey, this.transpKey);", but there is the problem. It just makes the pixel transparent and the pixels underliing will be visible.
Does anyone know how to force C# to replace pixels instead of leaving them? Or does anyone know a solution for my problem?
Thank you very much for reading, thinking and maybe helping.

//Edit:
OK, now I found out that I can use "e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;" to set that the pixel shall be replaced. But after that the transparency is destroyed. And the result is the same. Nothing erased. Any solutions?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want, but couldn't you call e.Graphics.DrawRectangle with a rectangle of size 1x1 to overwrite whichever pixel you want to overwrite, after you call e.Graphics.DrawImage but before you call e.Graphics.Dispose?

Comment: No. Firstly it wouldn't help me, because the text, line, rectangle or pixel which I want to erase are already overdrawn. And that's the problem. I can't erase the drawn pixels.  
I tried it by overdrawing the pixels, like you are using a rubber, and than making them transparent with the ImageAttribute. But there is the above mentioned problem, that the pixels I want to erase aren't erased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide my solution officially: I solved it by using several layers. Not clean but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ERASING because controls are drawn one by one, using z-order as drawing order.  First, form background is drawn, then labels, then your control.  There are no LAYERS, once something is drawn, its there to stay.

Only way to 'ERASE' something is to find a way for the controls that are UNDER your control to redraw themselves into some kind of buffer of yours, which you could use.

I tried it long time ago, and have abandoned the method, because it's terrible to implement and extremely error-prone.

Sorry for the bad news, hope that you'll get some insight from my experience.

Comment: I'm using a costum control and I redraw it every draw-event ;). My question is about the System.Drawing.Graphics/Bitmap. The controls are ok.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of "erase"?  To me it means chaning the color to that of the background.  Don't use transparency to do that, just render the area in the color of the background.

Comment: Erase means for me, that I have transparency again. The solution with color isn't usefull because I have got the original image in background. The reason why I want this so much is that, that you can draw lines and rectangles, which can be draged. And every mousemove there is a new area drawn. And that area needs to be erased.

Comment: @user1141147 I'm not clear on the larger environment.  Are you layering transparent controlx, or did you implement on custom Bitmap-Designer and you simulate moving rectangles around like a sprite, or something else?  It may help if you edit the original question to give us all a gite more background if possible.

Comment: 2nd one. I solved it by using several layers and just clearing the layer. Not clean but it works.